# How to get unique values from @foreach Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get unique values in a drop down list. Code for drop down is:

```
@foreach ($allCourses as $courses)
    <option>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse( $courses -> start_date )->format('F') }}</option>
@endforeach
```

and controller is:

```
public function coursesCategories() {
    $allCourses = Courses::latest() -> get();
    return view('courses.courses_categories') -> with(compact('allCourses'));
}
```

This gives me all the values. For example, if there are multiple entries on same month, it gives me results like

**August**

**August**

**August**

**September**

**September**

But if there are multiple entries on same month, I want them to show once in the drop down. So the result will be like:

**August**

**September**

Comment: Well you can retrieve unique `Months` but what `Courses` field would you pass as the `value` of the `option` tag?. Because I think you want to give a `value` attribute to the `select option` otherwise your dropdown does not select anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter months using this query

```
$months= Courses::select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(start_date) month_name'))
        ->groupBy('month_name')
        ->orderBy('month_name', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

and fetch month names in blade

```
@foreach ($months as $month)
    <option>{{ $month->month_name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks Man it's Work, a lout of thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could try a unique() method on collection.

```
$allCourses = Courses::latest() -> get()->unique('start_date');
```

Comment: First Thanks for Your Respond, I Know this code but in need Just Unique Month not all Date